# How can I catch the JSON in bottlepy response in after_request?

Tags: python, bottle

I want log all web-services response with Bootle Py.
What is the best way?

I'm writting to a MongoDB database with this code:

```
@hook('after_request')
def f_after_request():
    if request['bottle.route'].rule not in [
        '/robots.txt',
        '/favicon.ico',
    ]:
        json_in = None
        if request.method not in ['GET']:
            json_in = request.json
        _save_in_out_message(
            url=bottle.request.url,
            json_in=json_in,
            json_out=bottle.response.get_data(),
            status_code=response.status_code,
            method=request.method
        )
```

But `response.get_data()` does not exists.

How can I catch the JSON in bottlepy response in after_request?

What is the correct `response.get_data()` command?

Thanks

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21785056/2196316.  Recommendation for using plugin like http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/plugindev.html#how-plugins-work-the-basics