# Returning HTTPResponse object in bottle loses response headers

Tags: python, web, cors, bottle

I have a bottle server (whose underlying http server has been swapped out with a multi-threaded CherryPy) in which one of my routes (a 'POST')returns an HTTP response instead of a json dictionary directly, eg:

```
return HTTPResponse(status=200,body=json.dumps({'body':'my body'})
```

Now, I have added '`after_request'` hook to my bottle app so that it will set headers on the response to handle CORS, eg, in my `after_request` hook I have:

```
bottle.response.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
```

And I can confirm the `after_request` function runs and sets the headers successfully on `bottle.response`.

BUT, my route function returns BEFORE the after_request function runs, and so my browser still sees none of those headers in the response message.

However, if I just modify my route function to return a simple json dict, instead of `HTTPResponse`, eg:

```
return json.dumps({'body':'my body'}
```

Then suddenly, the browser sees the headers set by my after_request hook. Even though the rest of my code is unchanged.

What gives? Why does returning `HTTPResponse` makes me lose all the headers, but returning just a simple json does not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the headers in the new object that you're returning, like this:

```
return HTTPResponse(status=200, body=json.dumps({'body': 'my body'}, headers={'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'})
```

My guess is that the `after_request` hook is operating on the "magic" response object that Bottle manages for you - so when you create and return a *new* one, its headers aren't modified.

Comment: Thanks, yes that of course is a workable that I'd rather avoid, as it makes it look ugly and defeats the after_request hook.

Comment: Why do you feel it's important to have an `after_request` hook? (In my experience, Bottle plugins work much better. But why do you need either in this case?)

Comment: Many similar bottle servers running, setting the same kind of headers again and again does not seem like a good practice.

Comment: Yeah, I see your point - in that case you might want to consider using a plugin. Here's an [example plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21785056/593047) that you might be able to adapt.